# What does JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT serialize for LocalDate?

Tags: java, jackson, java-time, jackson2, jackson-databind

Consider example:

```
public class MyDto {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT)
    private LocalDate dob;
}
```

Leads to `{"dob":17918}` when `new Date().getTime()` return `1548155501766`

It does not look like seconds or milliseconds. So What is the number?

**Note**

Java time module for Jackson included to object mapper.

Answer (score 1):

From the following source code : [LocalDateSerializer.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/master/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/LocalDateSerializer.java)

```
    if (_shape == JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT) {
        g.writeNumber(date.toEpochDay());
    }
```

You can see that in the case of `JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT` , the number you get is the result of calling [toEpochDay()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) on your `LocalDate` object.

Comment: The example value, 17918, corresponds to 2019-01-22. This date was returned from `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(17918)`.

Comment: I thought dates needed to be a Long, not an Int?

Answer (score 0):

The date getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. I suspect that the asker knew this already. I don’t think you are answering the question.